# Mac Command Line - List Available Serial Ports?

Tags: macos, command-line, serial-port

on my Mac, i currently have the available serial ports:

- /dev/tty.usbserial-A700dYoR
- /dev/cu.usbserial-A700dYoR
- /dev/tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
- /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem
- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem

is it possible to retrieve a list of the available serial ports of the computer from the command line (terminal)?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

ah... it is much easier than i though.

```
ls /dev/tty.*
ls /dev/cu.*
```

will list

- /dev/tty.usbserial-A700dYoR
- /dev/tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
- /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem
- /dev/cu.usbserial-A700dYoR
- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem

Answer (score 88):

You can do it with a single command:

```
ls /dev/{tty,cu}.*
```

Comment: You have an extra 'u' at the end of regex. It should be just: `ls /dev/{tty,cu}.*`