# How to get serial port list in Mac OSX using TCL

Tags: tcl

I want get list of all serial ports in my Mac OSX for writing a `.img` file to particular modem. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this other Stack Overflow question and its answers:

> [Mac Command Line - List Available Serial Ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815211/mac-command-line-list-available-serial-ports)

you do this:

```
set serialPorts [glob -directory /dev "{tty,cu}.*"]
```

On my Mac (your hardware may vary) I get this in the resulting list:

```
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
```

Comment: above code is not worked for me. But this line worked for me set serialPorts [glob  /dev/cu.*].